# Reading assembly version information and custom attributes in CoreCLR

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, coreclr

I wonder how to read assembly version information in the new CoreClR either with a name of the assembly where code is currently executing or explicitly giviging the name of the assembly or preferably a type in some assembly (can be statically referenced)?

I have code like the following (currently I really care about assembly version)

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


public class AssemblyInfo
{
    private readonly Assembly assembly;

    public AssemblyInfo(Type type)
    {
        assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(type);
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return CustomAttributes<AssemblyTitleAttribute>().Title; }
    }

    public Version AssemblyVersion
    {
        get { return assembly.GetName().Version; }
    }

    public string FileVersion
    {
        get { return FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location).FileVersion; }
    }

    private T CustomAttributes<T>() where T: Attribute
    {
        var customAttributes = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false);
        if(customAttributes.Length > 0)
        {
            return (T)customAttributes[0];
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

with usage such as

```cs
var info = new AssemblyInfo(typeof(SomeClassInSomeAssembly));
```

**<edit:**
As commented to Ramin's otherwise nice answer, if that should work, I wonder if there's something else going on here. I get an error message already by referencing `Assembly` and VS 2015 RC doesn't suggest adding anything. The error messages is basically `Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Assembly' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) CoreClrConsoleApp1.DNX Core 5.0\CoreClrConsoleApp1\src\CoreClrConsoleApp1`.

My project.json is

```
"frameworks": {
"dnx451": { },
"dnxcore50": {
  "dependencies": {
    "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-22816",
    "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-22816",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-22816",
    "System.Runtime.InteropServices": "4.0.20-beta-23019",
    "System.Reflection": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo": "4.0.0-beta-22816",
    "netfx-Reflector": "1.0.0.10"
```

<edit: It was something with my setup as when I created a new project, `Assembly` is recognized. There is one method, `Assembly.Load`, besides the two inherited from `object`. I can use this to load an assembly and consequently get the version information I desire. Or I would, but when I try to run the application, it crashes with a message *System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to resolve the following dependencies for target framework 'DNXCore,Version=v5.0'*. This is strange, as I've ran `dnu restore`, I get success, but still `dnx . run` won't work. I tried already `dnvm install -r coreclr latest` (with both x86 and x64) and also checked with `dnvm use` a framework is selected.

The custom argument code could be (composing on top of my head):

```
private string CustomAttributes<T>() where T : Attribute
{
    var customAttribute = assembly.CustomAttributes.Where(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(T)).FirstOrDefault();
    if(customAttribute != null) { return (string)customAttribute.ConstructorArguments[0].Value; }

   throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(type).GetName().Version
```

Or

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(assemblyName)).GetName().Version
```

Or, if you want to load the assembly at run time

```
Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath).GetName().Version
```

Comment: I think I should have been more specific (alas, kids making ruckus), but when I try to reference ``Assembly``, I get an error message ``Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Assembly' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) CoreClrConsoleApp1.DNX Core 5.0\CoreClrConsoleApp1\src\CoreClrConsoleApp1``. I haven't found what's the beef, VS doesn't propose to add anything either.